# Easiest way to Upload Html 5 Drag and Drop File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found various different way to upload html 5 drag and drop file. I am searching the best way to upload html 5 drag and drop file in all supported browsers(FireFox, Chrome, IE(using DropBox PolyFille), etc)? Drag and drop works in these browsers but I need to upload it?

Comment: I think that what you would be uploading would be the JavaScrip code to make use of the DnD framework provided by HTML 5.

Comment: @user482594, Just seearch Html 5 Drag Drop Upload

Comment: @Terry, Can you show an example.

Comment: @user960567 Hmm, I may have misinterpreted your question. If so, my apologies. I was thinking you were asking what Javascript code was needed to get html5 drag and drop to work and how you would get it. For example, http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/ has a link under Download Sample Code that let's you download html5.dnd-example.zip (which I just did to play with it). What I'm going to do is unzip it, get their example running, and then put the code in my application and modify it to suit. Again, I may be misunderstanding what you're wanting.

Answer (score 2):

One option is Plupload. You can check out it's features here: http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: This is not working in IE. See, DropBox which works in IE as well

Comment: Internet Exp 8. BTW, I need to upload the file on server. I know how to use Drag and Drop. Please show an example

Answer (score 1):

Try out this jQuery plugin: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You should be able to drag a picture to the browser window and have it be displayed in their UI, then it can be uploaded.

Comment: This is not working in IE. See, DropBox which works in IE as well.